# Removing Hashtag using Java WebFilter

Tags: java, regex, servlet-filters, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have the following configuration in the urlrewrite.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN" "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
    <rule>
        <from>^(/event/showEventList)(\.{1})(\bhtm\b|\bhtml\b)(\?{0,1})([a-zA-Z0-9-_=&amp;]{0,}+)(#{0,1})([a-zA-Z0-9-_=&amp;]{0,}+)$</from>
        <to type="redirect" last="true">/events$4$5</to>
    </rule>                 
</urlrewrite>
```

The regex `^(/event/showEventList)(\.{1})(\bhtm\b|\bhtml\b)(\?{0,1})([a-zA-Z0-9-_=&amp;]{0,}+)(#{0,1})([a-zA-Z0-9-_=&amp;]{0,}+)$` has 7 groups, which are:

1. `(/event/showEventList)`: matches /event/showEventList
2. `(\.{1})`: matches a single dot (.)
3. `(\bhtm\b|\bhtml\b)`: matches only htm or html
4. `(\?{0,1})`: matches question mark (?) which can may occur zero or one
5. `([a-zA-Z0-9-_=&amp;]{0,}+)`: matches the query string which can occur zero or more
6. `(#{0,1})`: matches hashtag (#) which can may occur zero or one
7. `([a-zA-Z0-9-_=&amp;]{0,}+)`: matches the fragment which can occur zero or more

If I test this configuration with a test URL: `/event/showEventList.html?pageNumber=1#key=val`, I am expecting that the redirected URL would be `/events?pageNumber=1`, but I am getting `/events?pageNumber=1#key=val`

I have a code snippet to test it, which is:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class UrlRewriterRegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "/event/showEventList.html?pageNumber=1#key=val";
        String regex = "^(/event/showEventList)(\\.{1})(\\bhtm\\b|\\bhtml\\b)(\\?{0,1})([a-zA-Z0-9-_=&]{0,}+)(#{0,1})([a-zA-Z0-9-_=&]{0,}+)$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);   
        System.out.println(matcher.replaceFirst("/events$4$5"));
    }
}
```

It outputs to: `/events?pageNumber=1`.

Any pointer would be very helpful.

Comment: I can provide the answer, but can you clarify this :  Do you want to remove any thing beginning from # character in your url?

Comment: @Rams, yes I just want to remove the [hashtag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

Comment: Is it just the # character or any thing after that including hash character?

Comment: @Rams, my requirement is to remove # and all the strings that come after it.

Comment: I provided an answer...hope that helps.... can you accept it as an aswer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am answering my own question, so that in future if someone else stumbles upon the same problem, this answer could help him.

There is nothing to do with the `UrlRewriteFilter` framework. By enabling the debug log for this framework I have seen that the URL it is receiving before applying the defined rules doesn't have the URL Hash(#). From other SO answers and by analyzing the network traffic of the browser, I saw that the browser does not send the URL fragment to the server so it's not available in the `HttpServletRequest`. This is the reason the Regular Expressions are not working.

Since this [hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash) is available in the client browser and thanks to [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) I am able to solve the problem using JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        const url = new URL(window.location);
        url.hash = '';
        history.replaceState(null, document.title, url);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: All the answers to the question are correct. Your question clearly mentions about url rewrite filter and noting about from where the # tag is coming from. For the example mentioned, the answers suggested are appropriate, and the answer you mentioned is not relevant to the question asked. Either change the question or ask a new question and answer it there

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify the expression a bit.

- Escape slashes, as they are typically used as delimiters for the regex `(\/event\/showEventList)`
- Remove superfluous quantifier `(\.)`
- Shorten the html string test `(htm(l)?)` - careful, this messes with your capturing group numbers
- Remove word boundary checks around `html`
- Use `?` instead of `{0,1}`
- Use `*` instead of `{0,}`
- Remove possessive quantifier (I don't see why you'd need it)
- Ignore everything after `#`, you don't seem to need it in your replacement

This gives us `^(\/event\/showEventList)(\.)(htm(l)?)(\??)([a-zA-Z0-9-_=&]+)*#(.+)$` which subsitutes your example to `/events?pageNumber=1`

To play around, see https://regexr.com/4otp7

Comment: Thanks for the valuable simplification. But the problem with UrlRewriteFilter still persists. It seems something to do with the API itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified the expression and here is the working solution

```
<from>^(\/event\/showEventList\.html?)(\?[a-zA-Z0-9-_=&]*)\#.*$</from>
<to type="redirect" last="true">/events$2</to>
```

This will match any thing and take everything from the beginning of query string till the first occurrence of #

**Explanation:**

Group 1 : Match the url /event/showEventList.html OR /event/showEventList.htm

Group 2 : Match all query string between o to many till the first occurrence of #

Group 2 is the string which you want to use for redirect and ignore any thing after # including #

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rams. I will add your Regex in my configuration and will let you know.

Comment: I have answers to my own question. Thanks for trying to help me.